# Redirecting whole website by htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using a wordpress and trying to redirect my whole website to new domain. I want website structure to remain same that is in this way:

"www.domain.com" **redirected to** "www.domain.ca"

"www.domain.com/post1" **redirected** to "www.domain.ca/post1"

As my site is of wordpress so htaccess already has some commands. I haven't changed those commands just added some more by that my site home page starts to redirects but not the whole site.According to my research "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ..." lets the whole website to redirect but unfortunately it is not. All of my htaccess code is given below. I have replaced my domain names in code.

**old domain:**www.domain.com

**new domain:** www.domain.ca

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.ca/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Thank You.

Comment: Try clearing your browser's caches and keep the rule above your wp rules

Comment: If you are using the same wordpress installation (different domain, same server) then you need to flush the wordpress rewrite rules. The easiest way is to go to the settings->permalinks in your wordpress admin and press save. (Beware that it will probably overwrite your .htaccess changes) https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: @starkeen Thanks dear. This solved the issue. Can you specify why it worked?